# ¿Cómo sería la cadena de conexión si me quiero conectar a la base Master y mi instancia es MSSQLSERVER?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Lo más simplificado posible. Solo quiero una cadena de conexión que funcione con los datos en cuestión (código de VB.NET).

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando autenticación Windows puedes usar la siguiente cadena de conexión:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Server=.;Database=master;Integrated Security=True;"
```

Si deseas usar autenticación basada en SQL puedes entonces usar la siguiente cadena de conexión:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Server=MyServer;Database=master;User Id=sa;Password=MyPassword;"
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. :)

Comment: Siempre a la orden.